# How to Access Component HTML output in Vue outside the template tag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I know that we can simply show the component output with `<ComponentName/>` inside the template,

but how do we access `ComponentName` html output outside the template like in `data`, `methods`, or during `mounted`

e.g. `components/Test.vue`

```html
<template>
    <div>I'm a test</div>
</template>
```

in another vue file `pages/ViewTest.vue`

```js
import Test from '~/components/Test.vue'
export default {
    components: {Test},
    data() {
        return {
            test: Test
        }
    },
    mounted: function()  {
      console.log( Test ) // Output is Test Component Object
      console.log( this.test ) // Output is Test Component Object
    }
}
```

The object from console log output seems to contain a lot of information and I can even see a `render` property from the object although when I try `console.log( Test.render() )` its giving me error

So My question is how can I get the `<div>I'm a test</div>` from outside the template?

Appreciate any help or guidance

**EDIT**

I'm using [vue-material-design-icons](https://github.com/robcresswell/vue-material-design-icons) package for generating different svg icons,

and I can use it like below

```html
<template>
  <MapMarkerRadius/>
</template>
<script>
  import MapMarkerRadius from 'vue-material-design-icons/MapMarkerRadius'
  export default {
    components: {MapMarkerRadius}
  }
</script>
```

Now here's my main issue,
I have this component that generates an html

```html
<template>
  <div :class="'card'">
    <div v-if="title" :class="'card-title'">
      {{ title }}
    </div> 
    <div :class="'card-content'">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'card',
  props: {
    title: {},
  }
};
</script>
```

Then I'm using that `card` component like this on a different `vue` file

```html
<template>
  <card :title="'Title ' + MapMarkerRadius">
    Test Content
  </card>
</template>

<script>
import card from '~/components/Card'
import MapMarkerRadius from 'vue-material-design-icons/MapMarkerRadius'
export default {
  components: {card, MapMarkerRadius}
};
</script>
```

and my problem here is that the output of the `card title` is `Title [object]`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) in the root of the `Test` component like :

```
<template>
  <div ref="test">I'm a test</div>
</template>
```

in other component do :

```
   mounted: function()  {
      console.log( this.$refs.test )
    }
```

> *No need to import the component*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is there no other way without using ```ref```? the component I'm trying to access is from an external package. so I can't really modify the the component and add the ```ref``` tag

Comment: I think there's no way, but you could reference it when you out it inside the template like `<Test ref="test"></Test>`, but what's your exact use case?

Comment: I've updated my question, can you review it again and see if that make sense? really appreciate your help man :)

Comment: Ok let me analyse your use case

Comment: what do you expect by ` <card :title="'Title ' + MapMarkerRadius">`? component name or the html content?

Comment: I need to display the component HTML content on the title

Comment: it's not possible to return the html content in this way, this is an object with some properties

Answer (score 0):

The repo that you are using are single-file components that generates html through a single tag, so using

```js
import MapMarkerRadius from 'vue-material-design-icons/MapMarkerRadius'
```

will enable you to use it in template as `<map-marker-radius/>`

That is why appending the string title and an object like `"My Icon"+MapMarkerRadius` will return the literal `[object]` as you've seen: `"My Icon [object]"`

You have 3 options to go through what you want:

1. Search for other repos that enable you to use easily material icons in other means;
2. You have access to the `card` component? You can use the class names of this repo instead rather than the svg version or the component itself: https://github.com/robcresswell/vue-material-design-icons/issues/12, add the class names to the props and add it to your component:

```html
<card :title="'Title'" :icon_class="map-marker-radius">
    Test Content
</card>
```

```html
<div v-if="title" :class="'card-title'">
      {{ title }} <div :class="icon_class"></div>
</div>
```

```js
props: {
    title: {},
    icon_class: '',
}
```

3. You can use the `MapMarkerRadius` component directly in `card` component but only appears when you pass a certain criteria on the `card` component, such like:

**main.vue**

```html
<template>
  <card :title="'Title'" :icon="true" :icon_typename="'map-marker-radius'">
    Test Content
  </card>
</template>

<script>
import card from '~/components/Card'
export default {
  components: {card}
};
</script>
```

with `icon_typename` as any name/keyword you'd like to use.

**card.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div :class="'card'">
    <div v-if="title" :class="'card-title'">
      {{ title }} <span v-if="icon_mmr"><map-marker-radius/></span>
    </div> 
    <div :class="'card-content'">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import MapMarkerRadius from 'vue-material-design-icons/MapMarkerRadius'
export default {
  name: 'card',
  props: {
    title: {},
    icon: { default: false },
    icon_typename: '',
    icon_mmr: false,
  },
  mounted(){
    if (this.icon && this.icon_typename === 'map-marker-radius') this.icon_mmr = true
},
  components: { MapMarkerRadius },
};
</script>
```

The code is far from perfect but you can go from there to optimize further.

Comment: the main reason I choose to use a component-based icons are for optimization, you know how the icons library can be so heavy if you load all the icons into your app, like even just the js file of fontawesome version 5 is about 1MB and there's no justice to load 1MB file if you only need 5 to 10 icons

Comment: I end-up not using ```card``` component if  need an Icon on the title,